# Is there any way to link from a React project to a vanilla JS one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Long story short, when I started learning JS I made a site for someone that didn't upload it online. Now, as I'm learning React, I bought a domain to make a portfolio with personal projects.

What I wanted to do is on the home page of my portfolio have like a few links to different projects. I was wondering if I could do something to somehow navigate to the vanilla JS project (which is not online, but stored locally on my computer) without having to rewrite it in React, as I'm still a beginner and that would take me some time

(Don't know if this is relevant or not but the vanilla JS site has multiple html and js files)

Comment: yep - just use a standard `<a href="...">`....

Comment: Sorry, I think it wasn't clear, I will edit the post in a sec, too. The vanilla js project isn't online, so I don't know if I could just use an anchor tag

Comment: Do you want to include the vanilla JS project inside of your React project? Because if the project isn't online, then you can't access it over the internet

Comment: Yup that's what I thought too, cause vanilla is so different from React, there's no way I can have both in the same project. I'll most likely just have to redo it. Thanks!

Comment: "there's no way I can have both in the same project", you can have them both in the same project. Are you asking how or you mean that in your current situation you just can't do it?

Comment: I am asking if it's possible and if yes, how

Answer (score 2):

React application is injected into any HTML element with `react-dom` package.

So given any vanilla project and a valid HTML, you just need to add an entry point like `<div id="myReactApplication"></div>`

```
<html lang="en">
  ...

  <body>
    <div>My vanilla application</div>
    <div id="myReactApplication"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And render the root of React application using [`ReactDOM.render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  return <>React Appliaction</>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("myReactApplication")
);
```

[image: Edit solitary-meadow-4e77k]

Comment: Ah I see. I will try this tomorrow. Thank you!!